# Docking on MDI Client area in C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I need Mdi application with docked panels on all sides of MainFrame.
but dock panels I created can't to be docked to center of the screen, because of MDI Client area.
Is there any way to hide or remove mdi client area and enable dock panes to be docked to center of the screen?
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: So you need an MDI application but without the MDI client? That's not an MDI application then.

Comment: I want to fill the screen with only docking panes. when i try to dock my panes to fill the screen, mdi client area is never hidden. I just want to fill the screen with only my docking panes.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issues with your design.

"Docking" itself means taking help of the sides of the window so that your panes can fit & rest over there.

If you want something to appear in the center then you would create a document that has a form view (CFormView). The form view will use the pane's dialog template.

Comment: I just want to fill the screen with only my docking panes. But mdi client area is still remain.

Comment: if then, is it possible to popup view(CFormView) from MDI Client area?